# Refactoring this legacy application to a cleaner state (continued)

Tags: c#

This is continued from here:

[Refactor a legacy application to a less-unwieldy state](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/55795/refactor-a-legacy-application-to-a-less-unwieldy-state)

I am refactoring a legacy application. I DO NOT have the ability to change the `Permissions`, `CustomerReport` or the `ListItems` classes. They are in external dlls that are given to me. I realize that the ref usage is dumb and it makes NO SENSE. I am going to work with my peers to follow better practices.

This whole class looks ugly and mind you I have refactored some of it out into methods but it still is too large and unwieldy.

The code is used to return a `TreeViewItem` in VB. We are rewriting the front end into C# and I am using an API call to get the data from this service. So what I need is to hand the front end something reusable for every call to this report service.

I am mainly focused on cleaning up the `AssembleNodes` method, but any and all help is great.

```
public class ReportService : IReportService
{
    private readonly Permissions _permissions;

    public ReportService()
    {
        _permissions = new Permissions();
    }

    public IList<Node> GetFor(string userGroup)
    {
        var listItems = new List<ListItem>();
        //Yes this is silly since statusReturn is never used
        var statusReturn = _permissions.GetReportsForUserGroupName(userGroup, ref listItems);
        return AssembleNodes(listItems);
    }

    public IList<Node> GetFor(int userKey)
    {
        var listItems = new List<ListItem>();
        //Yes this is silly since statusReturn is never used
        var statusReturn = _permissions.GetReportsForUser(userKey, ref listItems);
        return AssembleNodes(listItems);
    }


    //I want to refactor this method down more
    private static List<Node> AssembleNodes(IList<ListItem> listItems)
    {
        var nodes = new List<Node>();
        if (!listItems.Any()) return nodes;
        var initialReportType = listItems[0].value;
        var initialCrs = listItems[0].key;
        var parent = AssembleNode(initialReportType);
        var child = AssembleNode(initialCrs, parent);
        foreach (var item in listItems)
        {
            var customerReport = (CustomerReport) item.dataObject;
            var grandChild = AssembleGrandChild(child, customerReport);
            if (item.value.Equals(initialReportType))
            {
                if (!item.key.Equals(initialCrs))
                {
                    initialCrs = item.key;
                    parent.Children.Add(child);
                    child = AssembleNode(item.key, parent);
                    child.Children.Add(grandChild);
                }
                    child.Children.Add(grandChild);
            }
            else
            {
                initialReportType = item.value;
                initialCrs = item.key;
                parent.Children.Add(child);
                nodes.Add(parent);
                parent = AssembleNode(item.value);
                child = AssembleNode(item.key, parent);
                grandChild = AssembleGrandChild(child, customerReport);
                child.Children.Add(grandChild);
            }
        }
        parent.Children.Add(child);
        nodes.Add(parent);
        return nodes;
    }


    private static Node AssembleNode(string value, Node parent = null)
    {
        return parent.IsNotNull() ?
            new Node(parent) { Text = value, Value = value } :
            new Node { Text = value, Value = value };
    }

    private static Node AssembleGrandChild(Node child, CustomerReport customerReport)
    {
        return new Node(child)
        {
            Text = customerReport.FileName,
            Value = customerReport.ReportKey.ToString(),
            Title = customerReport.Description
        };
    }
}
```

I really want to refactor this to a better state; any suggestions?

Comment: Can you comment it to explain what it's supposed to do now?  It looks like you're transforming a list into a tree but it's not clear what the rules are.  It's confusing that you keep updating `initialReportType`, it's not initial anymore.

Comment: @Robert, you have your else statement indented too far.

Comment: This won't compile. `gmcListItems` is never declared.

Comment: Sorry fixed. Didn't sanitize new code

Comment: After reading the last incarnation of this question, `} child.Children.Add(grandChild);` should have an `else` in there, not just be free-floating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hey Rocky! Watch Me Pull A Rabbit Out of my *Hat***

If you're a Rocky & Bullwinkle fan you know how that always turned out!  Well, here goes ...

It looks like every `ListItem` generates a parent, child, and grandchild node. So, how about we generate all the nodes first, holding them in parent, child, grandchildren `Dictionary`s. Then adding to `Node.Children` collections is simple.

**Extension Methods**

Great for putting "core" things in understandable terms. Even without all the `Dictionary` craziness I think you should implement some Extension methods first, then refactoring will be less confusing.

```
public static class ListItemExtensions{

    public static string NullParentKey (ListItem this item) {
        return string.Empty;
    }

    public static string ParentKey (ListItem this item) {
        return item.value;
    }

    public static string ChildKey(ListItem this item) {
        return item.key;
    }

    public static CustomerReport Report(ListItem this item) {
       return (CustomerReport) item.dataObject;
    }

    public static string GrandChildKey(ListItem this item) {
       return item.Report.ReportKey;
    }

    // Node class extensions do not need to be in a separate class

    // making the gross assumptions about how to access
    // the Node properties

    public static string Key (Node this node) {
        return node.Text;
    }

    public static string ParentKey (Node this node) {
        return node.Parent.Text;
    }
}

public class ReportService : IReportService {

    protected Dictionary Parents<string, IList<Node>> = new Dictionary<string, IList<Node>();
    protected Dictionary Children<string, IList<Node>> = new Dictionary<string, IList<Node>();
    protected Dictionary GrandChildren<string, IList<Node> = new Dictionary<string, IList<Node>();

    protected IList<Node> Nodes {get; set;}
    protected Node Parent {get; set;}
    protected Node Child {get; set;}
    protected Node GrandChild {get; set; }

// Yes, I did not wrap this code in a Method. I'm tired of manually indenting.

    foreach(ListItem item in listItems) {
        Parent = AssembleNode(item.ParentKey());
        Child = AssembleNode(item.ChildKey(), Parent);  
        GrandChild = AssembleGrandChild(Child, item.Report());

        if(! Parents.ContainsKey(Parent.Key))
            Parents.Add(Parent.Key, new IList<Node>()); 

        Parents[Parent.Key()].Add(Parent.Key(), Parent);

        if(! Children.ContainsKey(Child.ParentKey()))
            Children.Add(Child.ParentKey(), new IList<Node>());

        Children[Child.ParentKey()].Add(Child.ParentKey(), Child);

        if(! GrandChildren.ContainsKey(GrandChild.ParentKey()))
            GrandChildren.Add(GrandChild.ParentKey(), new IList<Node>);

        GrandChildren[GrandChild.ParentKey()].Add(GrandChild.ParentKey(), GrandChild);
    }

    foreach (var grandChild in GrandChildren) {
        foreach (var child in Children[grandChild.ParentKey()]) {
            child.Children.Add(grandChild);
        }
    }

    foreach (var child in Children) {
        foreach (var parent in Parents[child.ParentKey()]) {
            parent.Children.Add(child);
        }
    }

    foreach (var parent in Parents) {
        Nodes.Add(parent);
    }
```

Comment: I am a huge fan of extension methods. I try not to create them for my POCO's. I feel that in the future when the code has to be revisited a new developer (or even myself if its been a while) may have a hard time following what is going on in the code. You do however make very good points and in this case it may be beneficial to use them and take the time to add the XML comments expressing what it is doing.

Comment: Don't make things worse with extension methods, certainly. Extension methods keep clients from having to know details. They improve Single Responsibility Principle adherence. If I'm having to compose even 2 properties, or use an obscure variable for a clear concept, or parse the structure of a string (that should have been a class - we have many dozens of them) then extension methods to the rescue!

Answer (score 2):

you should move

```
child.Children.Add(grandChild);
```

outside of your if statements like so:

```
    foreach (var item in gmcListItems)
    {
        var customerReport = (CustomerReport) item.dataObject;
        var grandChild = AssembleGrandChild(child, customerReport);
        if (item.value.Equals(initialReportType))
        {
            if (!item.key.Equals(initialCrs))
            {
                initialCrs = item.key;
                parent.Children.Add(child);
                child = AssembleNode(item.key, parent);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            initialReportType = item.value;
            initialCrs = item.key;
            parent.Children.Add(child);
            nodes.Add(parent);
            parent = AssembleNode(item.value);
            child = AssembleNode(item.key, parent);
            grandChild = AssembleGrandChild(child, customerReport);
        }
        child.Children.Add(grandChild); // <--
    }
    parent.Children.Add(child);
    nodes.Add(parent);
```

Otherwise you are going to have a whole lot of duplicates.

Comment: That logic is correct. If the item.value == initialReportType but item.key != initialCrs then I need the current grandchild added to the current child

Comment: if ` if (item.value.Equals(initialReportType))` and `if (!item.key.Equals(initialCrs))` then you two children will be added

Comment: As you were typing that I ran my unit test and saw the failure